# Game engine lights not pointing to same place as in a render

Tags: game-engine, light

I'm working on an auditorium scene for my game. I set all the lights up and did a quick model of the mesh, and rendered it. It came out all right, but when I went into the game engine and started it, only two or three of the lights actually pointed to where I wanted it. Why?

[Blend file at pasteall.org](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/30152)

Blender Internal:
[image: Blender Internal Image]

Game Engine:
[image: Game Engine Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using GLSL shading instead of multitexture.

[image]

Multitexture shading shades the mesh per vertex. Since your object doesn't have many vertices where the lights should be illuminating, the results are misleading.

If you subdivide your mesh a lot, multitexture gives a more predictable result, but not as nice as GLSL:

[image]

Comment: This worked! I also had to set my view-port shading to Texture for this to work, which caught me for a second. Do you mind explaining why multi-texture gave me such funky results?

Comment: @KevinJohnson Yes, the game engine uses the viewport shading setting (to some extent). I updated my answer.